# Confusion in proof of (Row rank)$=$(Column rank) by Lang

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand proof of

> *Rank Theorem: row rank and column rank of any matrix are same*

given in Lang's Linear Algebra, Second Ed. $1972$ (p. $147-148$). He proceeds in following steps.

(1) Let $A=[a_{ij}]$ be an $m\times n$ matrix over a field $F$. Let $F^{(m)}=\begin{Bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ \vdots \\ x_m \end{bmatrix}: x_i\in F\end{Bmatrix}$.

(2) The map $L_A:F^{(n)}\rightarrow F^{(m)}$ given by left multiplication by $A$ is linear; its image is column space of $A$. If $U$ is the row-space of $A$, then $\ker L_A$ is the subspace $U^{\perp}$ of $F^{(n)}$ which consists of rows orthogonal (as dot product) to all rows of $A$. Thus,
$$
n=\dim\ker (L_A) + \dim Im(L_A)=\dim ({\rm row\, space\, of A })^{\perp}+ \dim({\rm Column\, space\, of \, A})
$$
(3) He uses following **Theorem 6** (page $140$) to get that
$$
\dim ({\rm row\, space\, of A })^{\perp}+\dim ({\rm row\, space\, of A })=n
$$
and concludes that row rank and column rank are same.

> **Question** Theorem 6 below is stated for vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with standard dot product. Thus, for above general rank theorem, I tried to see whether $$\dim W + \dim W^{\perp}=\dim V \hskip1cm (*)$$ is valid for $V=F^{(n)}$ ($F$ any field) with dot product; but I couldn't see proof of this identity. Can one state how can we prove (*)?

[image]

Comment: Theorem 6 is true for any field, provided $V=F^n$ and the inner product is given by the usual formula $x_1y_1+\cdots+x_ny_n$. Could you investigate whether Lang's proof of theorem 6 is valid in this context?

Comment: I was trying this (you said): If  $v.v\neq 0$, then it is easy to show that $v^{\perp}$ is of dimension one less than $\dim V$. But I couldn't proceed for general one. (To be specific, it may happen that $v.v=0$ for all $v\in V$, and specifically for fields of characteristic $2$. I stuck here actually!

Comment: Anyway, I don't like this approach at all. I'd use the fact that elementary row operations and column operations preserve both row rank and column rank. Now each matrix can be reduced using both types of operations to the shape $\pmatrix{I&O\\O&O}$.

Comment: In characteristic $p$, one can have $W\cap W^\perp\ne0$ but $\dim W+\dim W^\perp=n$ nonetheless.

Comment: There are other proofs, which long back I had seen on this site, with references from monthly articles too. But the proofs were involving some tricks. The proof by Lang was seeming me to be based on basis theorems which occur quite frequently in other contexts also, so I felt this proof to be based on natural arguments. (Also, I am not worrying about $W\cap W^{\perp}$ as we are considering their dimensions only. But I am not getting here direction.)

Comment: How about orthogonal projection of $V$ on $W$ ?

Comment: @user710290: But this need not be surjective (for general dot products), over any field, right?

Comment: @Beginner  Over a general field, a non-zero vector may be self-orthogonal which doesn't meet an essential criteria for being inner product space . And I can't see why the projection operator would not be surjective , any vector in the $W$ is the orthogonal projection of itself. Isn't it ?

Comment: @user710290: Instead of inner product over reals etc (in which, only zero vector is seld-orthogonal), an $n$-tuple over other field may be self-orthogonal w.r.t. dot product, and this is the case I want to consider. (Instead of inner product, you may take dot product of $n$-tuples over any field to avoid confustion)